# how to modify pentaho bi server home and login screen

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to modify the home page and the login screen, trying to remove some images and adding some links but the changes that I am applying doesn't appear to be reflecting. Is there any documentation on how to modify the Pentaho BI Server pages?

Tried the instructions on this thread: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?153494-Pentaho-CE-5-Customize-Home-Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, the changes will not reflect if I access the BI Server using the localhost url, but if I use the actual IP address of my machine, then I see the changes. Dunno why, but it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

apart from the thread you followed for doing changes if you understand JavaScript, Jquery and HTML then you can do modifications in below files according to your need.

```
biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\mantle\home\index.jsp ---Home Page changes

biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\jsp\PUCLogin.jsp --- Login Page Changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use tapa plugin, avaiable in marketplace, regards